# How to connect internet in ubuntu using the bluetooth connection?

Tags: internet, bluetooth

How to connect internet in ubuntu using the bluetooth connection? please provide some screen shots on those

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this was to connect my phone to my laptop using Bluetooth by going to the top right, clicking on the Bluetooth symbol, and selecting setup new device. Ubuntu 12.10 automatically recognized it as a network device after I did this, and I was able to surf the web using my phone. (I have a galaxy s3 running a custom rom)